# n-dimensional integral $\int_{R^n} \frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^n}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $\int_{R^n} \frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^n}dx$

For two dimensions, I was able to evaluate the above integral using polar coordinates. I was getting the answer as $\pi$. Applying hyper spherical coordinates for the general $n$ dimensions makes the integral very complicated due to the Jacobian. Is there an easier to computer this integral for higher dimensions?

--Minor edit---

A small typo in the power of the denominator.

Comment: Since $d^nx=r^{n-1}drd\Omega$, you need to multiply [a Beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas) by the [surface area of an $n$-ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Relation_with_surface_area). You should find the answer is $\frac{\pi^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma(n)}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @J.G. !

Comment: yes it does. Thanks a lot. @OliverDiaz